# Calculate battery state of charge percentage

Tags: voltage, batteries, battery-charging, math, capacity

What is the correct formula to calculate battery state of charge percentage based on the battery type (12v, 24v, 48v and so on) and the current battery voltage.

For example if I have a 12v battery and the battery has 12.06v left in it, it would give me around 50% capacity left.

I am looking for the formula used in this chart(12v battery type):

[image: Chart]

**UPDATE EXAMPLE OF MY CURRENT WAY OF DETERMINING STATE OF CHARGE:**

`function battery_percentage($voltage_type, $battery_voltage) {
        if($voltage_type == 12) {
            if($battery_voltage <= 10.5) {
                $battery_percentage = 0;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 11.31) {
                $battery_percentage = 10;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 11.58) {
                $battery_percentage = 20;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 11.75) {
                $battery_percentage = 30;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 11.9) {
                $battery_percentage = 40;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 12.06) {
                $battery_percentage = 50;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 12.20) {
                $battery_percentage = 60;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 12.32) {
                $battery_percentage = 70;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 12.42) {
                $battery_percentage = 80;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 12.5) {
                $battery_percentage = 90;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 12.6) {
                $battery_percentage = 100;
            } elseif($battery_voltage >= 12.6) {
                $battery_percentage = 100;
            }
        } elseif($voltage_type == 24) {
            if($battery_voltage <= 22) {
                $battery_percentage = 0;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 23.02) {
                $battery_percentage = 10;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 23.32) {
                $battery_percentage = 20;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 23.62) {
                $battery_percentage = 30;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 23.92) {
                $battery_percentage = 40;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 24.20) {
                $battery_percentage = 50;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 24.48) {
                $battery_percentage = 60;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 24.74) {
                $battery_percentage = 70;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 25) {
                $battery_percentage = 80;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 25.24) {
                $battery_percentage = 90;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 25.46) {
                $battery_percentage = 100;
            } elseif($battery_voltage >= 25.46) {
                $battery_percentage = 100;
            }
        } elseif($voltage_type == 48) {
            if($battery_voltage <= 45.5) {
                $battery_percentage = 0;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 46.04) {
                $battery_percentage = 10;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 46.64) {
                $battery_percentage = 20;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 47.24) {
                $battery_percentage = 30;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 47.84) {
                $battery_percentage = 40;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 48.40) {
                $battery_percentage = 50;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 48.96) {
                $battery_percentage = 60;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 49.48) {
                $battery_percentage = 70;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 50) {
                $battery_percentage = 80;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 50.48) {
                $battery_percentage = 90;
            } elseif($battery_voltage <= 50.92) {
                $battery_percentage = 100;
            } elseif($battery_voltage >= 50.92) {
                $battery_percentage = 100;
            }
        }`

Comment: Have you searched for this on here? Hint it has been asked many times....

Comment: I can't find anything, I'm not sure what the correct name/wording to use for exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: First result on here, looking for “battery stae of charge”... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/281065/152903

Comment: I have read that already and gives no formula

Comment: I'm just looking for the math that was used in the picture I used, I want to measure the battery percentage from two values(battery type and battery voltage)

Comment: Did you follow the answers???

Comment: Yes and it does not answer my question, I'm not worried about load and all that, I need the formula without any load on the battery.

Comment: Your misconception is that you're looking for a formula **that does not exist**.

Comment: Then how did they calculate the differences in the chart that I posted in the question.

Comment: The manufacturer did some **tests**, they **measured** it.

Comment: You say a 12V battery type as if there's only one type of battery that's 12V, but this isn't true, and SOC estimation will be drastically different for a 12V lithium-ion battery than it would for a 12V lead-acid, and very different again if it's a 12V NiMH battery.

Comment: I know that but I'm referring to battery voltage. I'm sure that you know what I mean.

Comment: Put the chart into excel and plot a curve fit.

Comment: @JoeSymonoski said what I was thinking

Comment: Can you handle a 5th order polynomial?  That will work well for AGM cells

Comment: Didnt you mean 12.6 v to start then battery goes to 11.06volts capacity is at 50% not 12.06v

Answer (score 2):

There **is** no correct formula to "measure" the state of a battery from it's open load voltage.

As Tony EE rocketscientist has already listed in his answer to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/281065/measuring-state-of-charge-of-a-battery) there are numerous factors that determine the open load voltage of a battery.

So the battery meters you find on your phone and any other device does not use a particular formula. Instead it is an educated **GUESS**. The manufacturer of a product with a battery will have some practical information resulting from tests **with that particular product** or a very similar product (like the previous model phone). Also some usage data and age might be considered. All that information is combined into a **guess** for the battery level.

That guess can be as simple as a lookup table like shown in your question, measure 12.20 V => show 60% battery full.

This not only applies to Lithium based batteries used in phones but also to 12 V car batteries.

Comment: I understand that but I am not exactly wanting a 100% accurate answer, I am building a monitoring system for tower sites, my system pulls the voltage if what the router states the battery is at. In my system, I define if the tower site is running a 12v battery or 24v and so on. I am looking for something that will give me a guessed answer like you stated by providing the battery voltage type and the read voltage from the battery(what my router states the voltage is), I have something already but Is only in increments of 10(0%, 10%, 20%...) but I need something that will be in increments of 1.

Comment: Is there any way I can do this by using a formula to give me a guess? Have a look at the updated question on how I am currently getting the SoC

Comment: Sure, it is called **interpolation** **however** you will **never** have a reliable 1% reading. Most battery level scales are crude because the value is a guess anyway. There is no point in displaying in 1% steps when 10% steps are already inaccurate. For example: if the battery was just loaded, it will have a slightly increased temperature. That temperature change by itself can already make the battery level appear more than 1% higher or lower.

Comment: I know that, I'm not worried about the correct readings, I just want to know how they calculated the difference in-between the values on the chart

Comment: You have already been told “the manufacturer did some tests and **measured** it”...

Comment: To do that a battery manufacturer would use a measurement device similar to this one: https://www.bkprecision.com/products/dc-electronic-loads/8600-150-w-programmable-dc-electronic-load.html  If you have to ask how much it costs then probably you cannot afford it. (Think 4 figure US$ number)

Answer (score 2):

I work this out as a pretty accurate solution based solely on the values it could be updated to detect battery and change the values based on that but I hard coded it for 24v and it works pretty good for what I needed.

```
$volt = 24.79; //this value is the only one that constantly changes.
$high = 25.46;
$low = 23.02;    
$sum = (($volt- $low) / ($high - $low)) * 100;
if (round($sum) >= 100)
    $sum = 100; // if greater than 100% then keep it there.
```

Answer (score 1):

The table can be put into excel then choose the line of best fit (trendline) by choosing a polynomial of the 2d degree you get:
y=0.2777x^2 - 5.9451x + 31.809

y being the percentage and x the voltage

Answer (score 0):

If your use case has pretty constant operating conditions wrt current rates, duty cycle, ambient temperatures etc, **and**

you have the gear and knowledge to determine **actual** SoC via controlled constant load testing down to 0% under "average" conditions **and**

the batteries are proactively replaced before they age much,

then extensive test benchmarking will allow you to create a table showing **rough** correspondence between **resting** or at least quiescent / low usage times voltage and guessed SoC.

Likely 10-20% accuracy at best, some of the time.

A coulometer to cross-reference with might help, but getting a proper OTS SoC meter to even 5% accuracy is several hundred dollars.

Answer (score 0):

There is good correlation between a battery's 'state of charge' and its internal resistance and none between its 'state of charge' and its open circuit voltage.

Battery testers utilise internal resistance and open circuit voltage readings to output results such as 'Recharge & Test', 'Good Battery - SOC XX %' and 'Bad battery'.